# How can I set a DatePicker to show empty selection by default?

Tags: xaml, maui

I have a .Net MAUI app that displays a DatePicker:

```
                <DatePicker 
                    x:Name="AppointmentDatePicker"
                    Date="{Binding AppointmentDate}"                         
                    Margin="10"  >
                    <DatePicker.Behaviors>
                        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
                            Command="{Binding AppointmentDateChangedCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding Date, Source={x:Reference AppointmentDatePicker}}"
                            EventName="DateSelected" />
                    </DatePicker.Behaviors>
                </DatePicker>
```

I need to show no date selected by default. If I set AppointmentDate property to null, the current date is displayed. This is confusing, as no date is in fact selected, so the user has wrong impression. How can I show no date selected by default?

Comment: May I know on which platform you are targeting to set a [DatePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/datepicker) to show empty selection by default?

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT iOS and Android. Of course, I would prefer to avoid using custom renderers and/or custom controls.

Comment: Yes, it would be great if the `DatePicker` supports nullable data format. However, it's not supported yet. Using custom renderers and/or custom controls is a trade-off solution. And I think it's also related with https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12600.

Comment: Wow we seriouly need a custom renderer to have a optional datepicker entry :'( so disappointing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to show no date selected by default.

You can use the Using [Custom Renderers](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Using-Custom-Renderers-in-.NET-MAUI) and custom control in .NET MAUI to create a `CustomDatePicker` that supports **nullable date**.

Here's a [working sample](https://github.com/divyesh008/CustomRenderers_MAUI) provided by divyesh. I've confirmed that it works fine in Android(see below screenshot) however in iOS custom renderer **this.Control** gives null.

You can follow up the link below if needed:

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12509

Screenshot in Android:

[image]